# What does "Windows recovered from unexpected shutdown" dialog actually do?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, crash

In Windows 7, after the OS detects it was shutdown in unusual manner (due to BSOD or power outage) upon logging in, it shows a corresponding dialog with a "Check online for a solution to this problem" button. After you press that button, it will look like this for some time, and then it disappears:

[image]

In all the years of using Windows 7 and encountering this dialog, I've yet to see some visible result.

What happens after I press that "check for solution" button? Is it supposed to ever tell the user something if a solution is (not) found? Is there a place like a bug tracker for all those reports with solutions open for public?

Comment: Developers have the option of connecting to this service.  Some developers do, some developers don't, Microsoft products do.  It submits data about the state of the program.  In this case Windows itself crashed, so it would send information on your system state, this answer doesn't have a specific answer.

Comment: open the "action center", here you have a reliable graph and all issues and here you can see solutions.

Comment: @magicandre1981 you could probably make that an answer

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you pressed the "check for a solution" button, the Error reporting sends the data (like minidumps + systeminformation or error logs) to Microsoft and when you open the "action center", you have a reliable graph and all issues and here you can see solutions:

[image]

[image]

In my case the issue was caused by not installing the VMware Tools inside the VM.

This error reporting was introduced in Vista and here you saw when bugs were fixed:

[image]

In the picture it was shown that the bug was fixed in the Vista RTM.